# How do I stop the loop from repeating once the user has entered the correct letters?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
  char code, name[50];

  int bal_paid, balance, bal_rem, tennis = 0, swimming = 0, Badminton = 0;

  printf("T for Tennis\n");
  printf(" B for Badminton\n");
  printf(" S for Swimming\n");
  printf("please enter your name:");

  scanf("%s", name);

  do {
    printf("\nPlease enter the amount you paid for the fees\n");

    scanf("%d", &bal_paid);

    printf("Please select a code : \n");

    scanf("%c", &code);

    scanf("%c", &code);

    if (code == 'T' || code == 't')
    {
      balance = 18000;

      bal_rem = balance - bal_paid;

      tennis = tennis + 1;

      printf("Hello %s your sport event is tennis. Your balance remaining is $%d", name, bal_rem);
    }
    else if (code == 'B' || code == 'b')
    {
      balance = 14000;

      bal_rem = balance - bal_paid;

      Badminton = Badminton + 1;

      printf("Hello %s your sport event is Badminton. Your balance remaining is $%d", name, bal_rem);
    }
    else if (code == 'S' || code == 's')
    {
      balance = 16000;

      bal_rem = balance - bal_paid;

      swimming = swimming + 1;

      printf("Hello %sc your sport event is swimming. Your balance remaining  is $%d", name, bal_rem);
    }
    else if (code != 'T' || code != 't' || code != 'B' || code != 'b' || code != 'S' || code != 's')
    {

      printf("invalid code");
    }
  } while (code != 'T' || code != 't' || code != 'B' || code != 'b' || code != 'S' || code != 's');

  printf("the amount of people doing tennis is %d\n", tennis);

  printf("the amount of people doing tennis is %d\n", Badminton);

  printf("the amount of people doing tennis is %d\n", swimming);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The editor includes editing and formatting tools.  The one for _properly_ formatted source code is the `{...}` symbol.  (i.e. it will not properly format your code, but will make properly indented and formatted code look like properly indented and formatted code.)

Comment: Your test of `code != 'T' || code != 't' ...` is wrong. The code will either not be `T` or will not be `t`, for example so this will always be true, ergo infinite loop. It cannot be both `T` and `t` simultaneously. Change logical or to logical and.

Comment: I've update the post to make the code at least marked as code. But it's still barely readable due to inconsistent indentations and excessive use of unnecessary blank lines. Please edit further to make the code readable.

Comment: @kaylum added some beautification via online C formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this test:

```
while (code != 'T' || code != 't' || code != 'B' || code != 'b' ...)
```

to this:

```
while (code != 'T' && code != 't' && code != 'B' && code != 'b' ...)
```

The former will always yield true, regardless of the value of `code`.